# Invalid Grant on Azure

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0

```
Dim params As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
params.Add("client_id", AzureClientId)
params.Add("client_secret", AzureSecret)
params.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code")
params.Add("code", code)
params.Add("redirect_uri", UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query, "")))
params.Add("resource", UrlEncode("https://petterinfotjenester.onmicrosoft.com/ITAS_SSO"))


Dim content As New System.Net.Http.StringContent(createFromDic(params), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") 

Using wc As New HttpClient
        Dim url = String.Format("264d5697-62aa-4771-829c-39828b5309ae/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0")
        wc.BaseAddress = New Uri("https://login.windows.net/")
        result = wc.PostAsync(url, content).Result
End Using
```

And the print of result is:

```
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS65001: No permission to access user information is configured for '7686eb91-cfcd-4b89-b4db-422b52205848' application, or it is expired or revoked.\r\nTrace ID: a631793a-a02b-4d08-abbb-bc7340a87409\r\nCorrelation ID: 335493ad-685a-4147-9e03-218a0b2acab3\r\nTimestamp: 2015-04-15 06:38:27Z","error_codes":[65001],"timestamp":"2015-04-15 06:38:27Z","trace_id":"a631793a-a02b-4d08-abbb-bc7340a87409","correlation_id":"335493ad-685a-4147-9e03-218a0b2acab3","submit_url":null,"context":null}
```

Seems like I have not configured my Azure directory to allow this 'client', but the application is created on that domain and is given access.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an article on CodeProject on how I solved it. 
It all boiled down to:

**REMOVE THE ?api-version=1.0 from the end of your endpoint.**

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/897584/Authenticating-users-through-OAuth-in-Azure

Comment: Would you have another link ? this article seems like it was not yet approved, so it is not accessible... thanks

Comment: Should be available now
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/897584/Authenticating-users-through-OAuth-in-Azure

Comment: Well anyway, my solution was that you cannot log in throught oauth2 with live credentials, they didn't implement it yet...